# Allowing SSH access OpenSSH Windows 2019

Tags: windows, openssh, windows-server-2019

I am using OpenSSH on Windows 2019 Server for SFTP file transfers. I am wondering if it is possible to enable this to be able to SSH using Putty with the logins I have allowed in the sshd_config file? if so what might the setting be? When I do it now I get a "the service allows sftp connections only"

Comment: You are going to have to provide us the configuration file of the OpenSSH Server.  There might be multiple configuration files on the system, only one of them will be used, so be sure you provide the one that the server is actually using.  Yes; Of course you can SSH into your OpenSSH Server, it doesn't matter what SSH client you use to do that.